# How can I put a Call to Telephone button in PHP wordpress?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have used this button for the call for price button but it's not working well in Google Chrome.

```
<form action="tel:+923000000000"><button type="submit">Call For Price</button></form>
```

I am using this code in the short description field.
Please help me to resolve this issue.
Thanks.

Screenshot for this button
[image: Screenshot for this button]

Comment: What do you mean by "not working well"? What have you tried to make it work better? And how is this related to PHP?

Answer (score 5):

You can add a link with the prefix `tel`:

```html
<a href="tel:12346">Call For Price</a>
```

Then you can design the link using CSS, to make it look like a button.

[Read more](https://www.callrail.com/blog/add-click-to-call-button-website-html)

Answer (score 0):

use

```
<a href="tel:+1-415-659-6900">(415) 659 6900</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use anchor tag to create a clickable phone number as below

```html
<a href="tel:+923000000000" target="_blank">Call For Price</a>
```

Comment: it isn't valid HTML5  according to the HTML5 Spec Document from W3C https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element

Comment: Just updated the code @EdenMoshe